# ACF - Pick first or second value from comma separated values

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Everyone,

I have just started using ACF and mostly using  feature to show data uploaded from csv file. Everything is working fine.

But in some fields i have data in the form of comma separated values such as Fiery Red, Leafy Green, Sky Blue.

My current output works as follows.

```
Available Colors - Fiery Red, Leafy Green, Sky Blue
```

I want to achieve;

```
Available Color - Fiery Red

Available Colors - Fiery Red, Leafy Green
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `explode()` function to split a string into the array of values

So you have a string of colors, separated with a comma, where the comma is a delimiter:

```php
$colors = 'Fiery Red, Leafy Green, Sky Blue';
```

Now use the `explode()` function (here is a link to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)) to convert it to the array:

```php
$colors_array = explode( ', ', $colors );
```

As a result, you will get:

```
array(3)
(
    [0] => string(9) "Fiery Red"
    [1] => string(11) "Leafy Green"
    [2] => string(8) "Sky Blue"
)
```

Now, when you have an array of values, you can display only the first value:

```
echo $colors_array[0];
```

or the first two elements:

```
$output_array = array_slice( $colors_array, 0, 2 );

echo implode( ', ', $output_array );
```